# How Does Firebase App Distribution name distributions?

Tags: firebase-app-distribution

I was assuming Firebase App Distribution names distributions by the `versionName`. For me it displays empty value. There is only `versionCode` in brackets.

This is how it looks at firebase:
[image: Distribution entry]

Does anyone know what is the distribution name and how to verify it? Which command line tool can I use to determine distribution name based on `APK` file? I am using `dexguard` obfuscation tool and I think it might be related. When I check `versionName` via `aapt dump badging` on the uploaded `APK` it shows me correct `versionName`. Don't know why Firebase displays empty value.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing what you're seeing and what you're expecting to see?

Answer (score -2):

The name of the app distribution gets its value via your app's name that you've set in your code.